# android check if non market apps are allowed programmatically

Tags: android, google-play

how can I programmatically check if non market applications are allowed on the android phone?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can try this, it opens setting screen

**check for it**

```
import android.provider.Settings;

int result = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),  Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0);
```

**open settings**

```
Intent intentSettings = new Intent();
 intentSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(intentSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to open this screen only, if non-market applications are not allowed on this phone. Therefore I need to check if non-market applications are allowed first.

Comment: On Android > 4.0 the correct action is "android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PackageManager` class to do that, more information is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).